# How to use shared-element transition which animate between Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, shared-element-transition

I am using a view pager which contains three Fragment. Now I would like to use shared element transition between an ImageView1 in FirstFragment and ImageView2 in Second Fragment when it swipes. How to do this as to make this kind of transition We need to add fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(..), But in this case We are not explicitly making any fragment transaction.

Comment: Have you tried googling some tutorial?

Comment: Yes I have tried, But nothing helped me, As either its showing example between Activity or Between fragment (where you have fragmentTransaction entity, But in my case I have no control of Fragment transaction as its part of FragmentPagerAdapter)

Answer (score 1):

The view pager actually does some fragment transactions internally. But, the fragments are added ahead of time, not when the user swipes. So you won't see the animation.

What you can do to customize view pager's animation is implementing a custom `ViewPager.PageTransformer` and then applying it with `viewPager.setPageTransformer(yourPageTransformer)`.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer).

But, you'll have to handle the animations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had the same issue. Standard shared element transitions are not working between ViewPager pages.

So I wrote a [SharedElement ViewPager library](https://github.com/kirillgerasimov/Shared-Element-View-Pager) . It works both for transitions caused by onClick() events (viewPager.setCurrentItem(x) ) and page slides caused by user. The animation is bound to finger movement.

Take a look.

[SharedElementPageTransformer demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymgHt.gif)

#### Usage

1. Add all fragment from your ViewPager to the List in the same order.

```
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(hello_fragment);
        fragments.add(small_picture_fragment);
```

2. Create *SharedElementPageTransformer* presumably in *Activity.onCreate()*. 
   *this* refers to activity:

```
        SharedElementPageTransformer transformer =
                new SharedElementPageTransformer(this,  fragments);
```

3. Add shared transition by passing pairs of view ids, that need to be linked together

```
        transformer.addSharedTransition(R.id.smallPic_image_cat, R.id.bigPic_image_cat);
```

4. Set our *transformer* to ViewPager's pageTransformer **AND** onPageChangeListener.

```
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, transformer);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(transformer);
```

The only thing you may need is to create additional *ImageView* on the *RecyclerView* fragment on top of *ImageView* you need to animate. Then you can make a transition from it to *ImageView* on the target *ViewPager* page.